# Heap Space error - How to optimize this code

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am having **heap space errors** with the below code.

Anybody have any idea **how to optimize this code**.

This happens for large files [180MB]. The method parameter has around 50 metatag *key-values* corresponding to each locale. The error shows up after handling 4500 pages.

**Note:** I tried changing *foreach* **to** *iterator* to use *iterator.remove()* for freeing up space.

```
public static String myChildPropsToString(final UnicodeProperties myLayoutProps) {       
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myLayoutProps.size());

    final String[] matchTarget = new String[] { StringPool.RETURN_NEW_LINE, StringPool.NEW_LINE, StringPool.RETURN };
    final String[] replaceTargetBy = new String[] { "_SAFE_NEWLINE_CHARACTER_", "_SAFE_NEWLINE_CHARACTER_",
            "_SAFE_NEWLINE_CHARACTER_" };

     //COMMENTED TO TRY OUT ITERATOR.REMOVE
    //
    // for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myLayoutProps.entrySet()) {
    // final String value = entry.getValue();
    //
    // if (Validator.isNotNull(value)) {
    // StringUtil.replace(value, matchTarget, replaceTargetBy);
    //
    // sb.append(entry.getKey());
    // sb.append(StringPool.EQUAL);
    // sb.append(value);
    // sb.append(StringPool.NEW_LINE);
    // }
    // }

    final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> propsIterator = myLayoutProps.entrySet().iterator();
    while (propsIterator.hasNext()) {
        final Entry<String, String> entry = propsIterator.next();

        if (Validator.isNotNull(entry.getValue())) {
            StringUtil.replace(entry.getValue(), matchTarget, replaceTargetBy);

            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(StringPool.EQUAL);
            sb.append(entry.getValue());
            sb.append(StringPool.NEW_LINE);
        }
    }
    propsIterator.remove();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

From my code I am setting this to a parent properties obj as follows :

```
UnicodeProperties myParentProps = new UnicodeProperties();
//Set some values to parent
UnicodeProperties myLayoutProps = new UnicodeProperties();
//Set some values to child
....
myParentProps.setProperty("childProp",myChildPropsToString(myLayoutProps));
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated !

Comment: Why don't you just give the JVM more heapspace? `-Xmx`

Comment: I have already tried this..But this code eats up the memory and I feel we can do something with the code itself.

Comment: Is there a reason you call `propsIterator.remove()` outside of the while-loop?

Comment: I never thought of that. Thanks. Will try that out !

Comment: do you know what exact object is eating out your memory?

Comment: I just know that this method is causing the problem. I dont know exactly the object as such.

Comment: Moving the iterator.remove() didnt help either. Do you suggest any other ideas ?

Comment: I know this does not relate to your problem, but I think your StringUtil.replace method should return some value and you discard it

Comment: Question: are you saying that 'myLayoutProps' above has 50 key-value pairs, and you run the method myChildPropsToString over 4500 times?

Comment: @LJ2 I am importing around 5000 pages from an XML. Each page has around 50 locales and each locale has some meta tag information.This layout(page) info is stored in the DB with one column having this metatag information. So for each page, this method is invoked.

Comment: @hoaz Thanks for pointing that out. But I am using a Liferay API class which is internally assigning it to the string.

Comment: I don't think Liferay can bypass string immutability. As for your question you should do optimization outside of this algorithm and dispose processed pages and locales when they are processed.

Comment: @hoaz If i comment this method, the import goes ahead fine. That is why I was concentrating on this method. (I will check again about StringUtil)

Comment: I suppose you have external loop outside and data is accumulated in one big structure. This consumes your memory and at some point your application dies. What you need to do is to persist your changes somewhere after each iteration and dispose objects you used for transformations

Comment: @hoaz I have an outerloop having method variables but dont persist any values after the current page is processed.Do you mean the same? Also do you suggest any tool to pin point the datastructure causing this?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. When the page is processed you should free resources associated with it.

Comment: @hoaz Thanks for your guidance.I implemented the same iterator logic on the foreach populating these props and its faster now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the propsIterator.remove(); inside the while.

```
final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> propsIterator = myLayoutProps.entrySet().iterator();
    while (propsIterator.hasNext()) {
        final Entry<String, String> entry = propsIterator.next();

        if (Validator.isNotNull(entry.getValue())) {
            StringUtil.replace(entry.getValue(), matchTarget, replaceTargetBy);

            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(StringPool.EQUAL);
            sb.append(entry.getValue());
            sb.append(StringPool.NEW_LINE);
        }
        propsIterator.remove();
    }
```

Comment: I never thought of that. Thanks. Will try that out.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to help either. I even tried increasing the initial size of StringBundler (to avoid expanding later) but problem still persists

Comment: I implemented the same iterator logic on the foreach populating these props and its faster now ! Thanks for your help !